# T-SQL Recursive using CTE (Know the grand parent)

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion, common-table-expression

I would like to use a CTE expression to create a recursive query (BOM) of all materials being sold.  My CTE works fine but the problem is that I always want to keep the Grand Parent (the Finished Goods that is sold).    so if for example I have a BOM which includes ingredients which themselves have BOM, at the end, I want all ingredients for all levels but keep the finished good item, not the ingredient item that have a BOM.

Here's my CTE:

```
    With MyCTE
    as
    (
      Select    H.Item, H.BOMQuantity, D.ComponentItem, D.NetQuantity, 0 as Lvl
      From Manufacturing.BillOfMaterialHeader H
      Inner Join Manufacturing.BillOfMaterialDetail D On H.Item = D.Item And GetDate() BETWEEN D.EffectiveFrom And D.EffectiveTo
      Inner Join Common.Item I On H.Item = I.Item 
      Where I.ItemGroup = 'U006'

      UNION ALL

      Select    H.Item, H.BOMQuantity, D.ComponentItem, D.NetQuantity, Lvl + 1
      From Manufacturing.BillOfMaterialHeader H
      Inner Join Manufacturing.BillOfMaterialDetail D On H.Item = D.Item And GetDate() BETWEEN D.EffectiveFrom And D.EffectiveTo
      Inner Join MyCTE B On D.Item = B.ComponentItem
    )

    Select * 
    From MyCTE
```

So what I would like as "Item" is always the Item coming from the first part of the query within the CTE, the sellable product and then go trough the recursive thing to get all ingredients of all level...  But can't find the way.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Umm...I think you may have some mis-understanding of what a BOM actually is. It's a Unicode character used to indicate the endianness of a file or text stream. What do you mean it to be in this context - is it Bill Of Materials? Or am I being a bit thick?

Comment: @StevePettifer A Bill of Materials, perhaps?

Comment: It means bill of materials, it's a fairly standard term.

Comment: Yeah my brain has just caught up. But the question was tagged as byte order mark which is why I was a little confused!

Comment: Sorry about the confusion on the Byte Order Mark, I've added the tag BOM but didn't noticed it converted the sentence afterwards :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead

```
With MyCTE
as
(
  Select   H.Item as BaseItem, H.Item, H.BOMQuantity, D.ComponentItem, D.NetQuantity, 0 as Lvl
  From Manufacturing.BillOfMaterialHeader H
  Inner Join Manufacturing.BillOfMaterialDetail D On H.Item = D.Item And GetDate() BETWEEN D.EffectiveFrom And D.EffectiveTo
  Inner Join Common.Item I On H.Item = I.Item 
  Where I.ItemGroup = 'U006'

  UNION ALL

  Select   
      B.BaseItem,
      H.Item, 
      H.BOMQuantity, D.ComponentItem, D.NetQuantity, Lvl + 1
  From Manufacturing.BillOfMaterialHeader H
  Inner Join Manufacturing.BillOfMaterialDetail D On H.Item = D.Item And GetDate() BETWEEN D.EffectiveFrom And D.EffectiveTo
  Inner Join MyCTE B On D.Item = B.ComponentItem
)

Select * 
From MyCTE
```

Comment: Thanks podiluska, works fine.  Can't find anything today, should have stayed in bed...